# explicitly I need to send Autoplayinterval option in jssor slider

Tags: java, jssor

I want to give autoplayinterval option to the jssor slider by click a button explicitly. I need to send different speed values to the autoplayinterval option through onclick function

Answer (score 1):

You can set idle interval (known as `$Idle`) explicitly for each individual slide in following manner.

```
<div id="slider1_container"...>
    <div u="slides" ...>
        <div idle="3000">...</div>
        <div idle="2000">...</div>
        <div idle="5000">...</div>
        <div idle="6000">...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And you can set idle attribute for each slide dynamically in javascript anytime.

Comment: Can you please show how to set the idle time with javascript after the page is loaded? Thanks you sir.